# How to develop a cryptocurrency pricing monitor using firebase and google cloud platform with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, backend

I am developing a cryptocurrency price monitoring app, that records the highs and lows of each coin set by the user and I have currently done everything except actually price monitoring. I have done the research and I couldn't find anything in GitHub, medium, or StackOverflow on anything closely related to what I'm looking for. For more context, this is what I'm trying to implement
[Figma design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWfCd.png)

and for you to have an idea of what exactly I'm  trying to build this is exactly the feature but implemented with kotlin instead of flutter
https://medium.com/google-cloud/developing-a-cryptocurrency-price-monitor-using-firebase-and-google-cloud-platform-34d5538f73f6

Anybody has an idea a tutorial, article or GitHub repo I can reference to implement this, please.

this is my GitHub repo for the project in case you want to check
https://github.com/maoja37/Cryptowatch .

Answer (score 1):

The question is no so clear, I looked into the Github repo, but there seems no code yet.

If you're looking for the price API, then the Coinmarketcap API is a good to go. Take a look at this [official document](https://medium.com/mycrypto/the-ethereum-virtual-machine-how-does-it-work-9abac2b7c9e)